# error during FindClass: org/webrtc/Camera1Enumerator

Tags: android, webrtc, quickblox, videochat, setcontentview

I got this error

> Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance"
>   error during FindClass: org/webrtc/Camera1Enumerator

while calling

```
setContentView(R.layout.video_call_layout);
```

The **video_call_layout** contains

```
<com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.view.RTCGLVideoView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/localView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        />

    <com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.view.RTCGLVideoView
        android:id="@+id/opponentView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_caller_login"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_caller_login" />
```

Anyone is there for help. I updated the latest jniLibs from [quickblox](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat-webrtc/src/main/jniLibs).

Comment: Have a look into [This](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/issues/443) if you already not.

Comment: which version of QuickBlox Android SDK do you use? latest (3.5.1)?